# Form Personalization: Loop through all the records and check for negetive price

Tags: oracle, forms, loops, oracleforms, personalization

The goal is to disable Pick release when in the shipping transaction form when the Unit Selling Price is negative. 
I want to validate all the sales order lines by looping through them.

I am using the WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD Trigger Event with no luck.

Is it possible to use loops in form personalization?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: I believe my question is complete. If you have trouble understanding the question please ask what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by the following code snippet:

```
first_record;
loop
  -- Do your check here
  exit when :system.last_record  = 'TRUE' ;
  next_record ;
end loop ;
```

However maybe in your code if Pick release is a button you can disable the button in `when-new-record-instance` if the unit selling price is negative.

Comment: Thanks! But I am not talking about form customization in form builder but form personalization. In Oracle apps the navigation goes Help> Diagnostic> Custom Code> Personalize.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE not the WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD. on the actions tab use the builtin type DO_KEY and argument NEXT_RECORD
ON the condition set it to :system.last_record <> 'TRUE'